# Visual Studio not building in Win32 OpenSSL 1.1.1u (Static)

Tags: c++, x86, openssl, visual-studio-2019, win32-process

I have tried to build my code in Visual Studio 2019 using **Win32** solution platform with **OpenSSL 1.1.1u (Static Library)** but it resulted in a **LNK2001: unresolved external symbol error**

```
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _EVP_EncryptUpdate@20
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _EVP_EncryptInit_ex@20
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _EVP_EncryptFinal_ex@12
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new@0
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free@4
```

Only the other platforms such as **x64** and **ARM64** will build normally.

How do I resolve this issue?

I have included libssl.lib, libcrypto.lib and the OpenSSL header files in the solution. I have also tried to build OpenSSL in 32-bit environment and Perl configurations.